# Perforce changelist diff view

Tags: perforce, p4eclipse

Is there a way to see a (preferably graphical) view of the changes in a changelist|changeset?
I am talking about a diff, showing only the removed lines in red, the added ones in green, with a few lines context, maybe highlighting the changed regions within lines in some way, listing unchanged files as unchanged, etc.

Is it possible preferably with P4Eclipse or worst case P4V or some external tool?

Comment: You can do a comparison between workspace file and a given revision from within the perforce client.

Comment: I want to do a comparison between all files in a changelist and their corresponding previous versions. Consider the case of a changelist with 500 changed files (not so unusual). Then manually diffing each one becomes a non-option. Or consider diffing branches...

Answer (score -1):

You can use P4 diff tool (Ctrl+D) which allows you to compare changelist against other changelist. You can try to make it work also via p4 command line tool and then you can filter differences you want to list.

Answer (score -1):

You can use any of the code review tools out there : they let you see all files in a changelist and exactly the parts of the files changed (unless you want to see the entire files).

A quick easy way for a small manageable number of files is also to redirect the p4 diff output to your text editor, for instance vim , and make use of the color schemes in it.